# The set of convergence of a power series is the same as that of a series with shifted coefficients

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-writing, solution-verification, power-series

I have the following problem

> For a fixed $ m \in \mathbb{N}$, show the sets of convergence of the series $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }a_{n}z^n$ and $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }a_{m+n}z^n$ are equal.

I have written the following argument:

Suppose that for $z_0 \neq 0$ the series $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }a_{n}z_0^n$ converges. Then, if $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }a_{m+n}\cdot z_0^n$ were to converge, we must have
$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }a_{m+n}\cdot z_0^n=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }a_{m+n}\cdot z_0^{m+n}\cdot z_0^{-m}=z_0^{-m}\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }a_{m+n}\cdot z_0^{m+n}=z_0^{-m}\sum _{n=m+1}^{\infty }a_{n}\cdot z_0^{n}$$
And we know this last expression converges because it's the product of a constant and the tail of a convergent series, then $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }a_{m+n}\cdot z_0^n$ must also converge and we have
$$\{z\in \mathbb{C} \ \mid \sum _{n=1}^{\infty }a_{n}z^n \  converges\} \subseteq \{z\in \mathbb{C} \ \mid \sum _{n=1}^{\infty }a_{m+n}z^n \  converges\} $$

Likewise, suppose $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }a_{m+n}\cdot z_0^n$ converges and if $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }a_{n}z_0^n$ were to converge then we must have
$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }a_{n}z_0^n=\sum _{n=1}^{m }a_{n}z_0^n + \sum _{n=m+1}^{\infty }a_{n}z_0^n=\sum _{n=1}^{m }a_{n}z_0^n + \sum _{n=1}^{\infty }a_{m+n}z_0^{m+n}=\sum _{n=1}^{m }a_{n}z_0^n + z_0^m\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }a_{m+n}z_0^{n}$$
And because we know this last expression converges, we must have that
$$ \{z\in \mathbb{C} \ \mid \sum _{n=1}^{\infty }a_{m+n}z^n \  converges\}\subseteq\{z\in \mathbb{C} \ \mid \sum _{n=1}^{\infty }a_{n}z^n \  converges\}  $$
and then they're equal.

My doubts about this argument are that I'm wary about doing algebraic manipulations on the series I want to show are convergent because I'm worried I might have implicitly assumed what I was trying to prove. I would greatly appreciate it if someone could help see why exactly I can or can't do this. Thanks!

Comment: It looks fine to me.

Comment: Great, thank you!